# Is this possible to create a Glassware without voice command?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to create a `Glassware` app. But, I cannot use the default listed voice commands of `Google`.

But, if I don't use any voice command, then I cannot see my `Glassware` app on `Google Glass`.

I would like to know if I can create a `Google Glassware` without voice commands ? I want navigate to my `glassware` only through `touch pad` (i.e., I need a launcher icon with out using any voice command )

If I use the following in `manifest.xml` then its not showing a launcher icon on Google Glass.

```
    <activity
                    android:name=".MyActivity"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_my" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

But, if I use the following code in `Manifest.xml` then its showing launcher.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:value="0"
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/customVoiceCommand" />
        </activity>
```

But, I do not want to use any voice commands for my `glassware`. If I dont use then its not showing the `launcher icon`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't think that there is any way to do this.

Google is really pushing for Glass to be a handsfree device; it's one of the major features of Glass - so I don't think that there is any way for you to add the app **only** when navigating with the touchpad, and not after saying "OK, Glass...".